# Sum of All Combinations of Products of Two Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, summation

Suppose that $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ are square, diagonalizable matrices. Consider the following infinite sum of all combinations of these two matrices:
\begin{align} \mathbf S = \mathbf I &+\mathbf A + \mathbf B +\\
&+\mathbf A^2 + \mathbf A\mathbf B + \mathbf B\mathbf A + \mathbf B^2+ \\
&+\mathbf A^3 + \mathbf A^2\mathbf B + \mathbf A\mathbf B\mathbf A+ \mathbf A\mathbf B^2 + \mathbf B\mathbf A^2+ \mathbf B\mathbf A\mathbf B+ \mathbf B^2\mathbf A + \mathbf B^3+\\
&+\cdots
\end{align}
Let $\mathbf A=\mathbf Q_A\mathbf \Lambda_A\mathbf Q_A^{-1}$, and $\mathbf B=\mathbf Q_B\mathbf \Lambda_B\mathbf Q_B^{-1}$ be the eigendecompositions of $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$.

If $\mathbf B=\mathbf 0$, then the sum would be equal to
$$\mathbf S = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbf A^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(\mathbf Q_A\mathbf \Lambda_A\mathbf Q_A^{-1})^k=\mathbf Q_A \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\mathbf\Lambda_A^k\right)\mathbf Q_A^{-1}.$$

> Is there a general way to express $\mathbf S$ as a function of $\mathbf Q_A$, $\mathbf Q_B$, and sums that involve $\mathbf \Lambda_A$ and $\mathbf \Lambda_B$?

Comment: Formally, the sum of all products of length $k$ is
$({\bf A} + {\bf B})^k$. In particular, if ${\bf A}, {\bf B}$ commute, they are simultaneously diagonalizable, so we can take ${\bf Q}_A = {\bf Q}_B$, and then $S$ Is given by the same formula as above but replacing ${\bf \Lambda}_A^k$ with $({\bf \Lambda}_A + {\bf \Lambda}_B)^k$.

Comment: In general, though, I don't think one can expect a formula in terms of ${\bf Q}_A, {\bf Q}_B$, and sums that involve ${\bf \Lambda}_A$ and ${\bf \Lambda}_B$ but not ${\bf Q}_A$ or ${\bf Q}_B$, since they contain the data of the relative positions of eigenspaces of ${\bf A}, {\bf B}$. In general, the eigenvalues of a sum ${\bf A} + {\bf B}$ of two matrices cannot be determined (completely) from the eigenvalues of ${\bf A}$ and ${\bf B}$.

Comment: Just a thought: is $S = I + AS + BS$?

Comment: following up on @Travis comments: in fact the key is that $S = \sum^\infty_{k=0} C^k$ where $C = A+B$, and so there is a nice formula depending on the decomposition of $C$.  However, there is no guarantee $C$ is diagonalizable, so you might need the Jordan form, etc.